# How can I show image with URL in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt

I used this code

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
import urllib

url = 'http://example.com/image.png'    
data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
pixmap = QPixmap()
pixmap.loadFromData(data)
icon = QIcon(pixmap)
```

URLs I want to use :

http://www.0404.go.kr/imgsrc.mofa?atch_file_id=FILE_000000000006873&file_sn=1
http://www.0404.go.kr/imgsrc.mofa?atch_file_id=FILE_000000000002230&file_sn=1
.
.
.

These URLs are from Korean Government API. I think I have wrong URL. How can I show these image?

Comment: You can't download the images?

Comment: Could you explain me better, do you want to download the images or just show them? I've tested your code and it works fine.

Comment: I just want to show them. not download it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the links do **not** contain the images directly, they just run a script on the server which initialize download. Therefore, you cannot use the links to display the pictures (note the example link ends with `image.png` which directly refers the image file, while your links contain just some query data). You will have to download them (alternatively, you could upload them on a different location, such as http://imgur.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for the links you posted, you just need to assign the pixmap to a widget that can be displayed onscreen. The `QIcon` class is not meant to be displayed directly.

A simple way to do this is to use a `QLabel`

```
label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
label.setPixmap(pixmap)
label.show()
```